# How to place a multicolumn figure above a single column figure and a single column table?

Tags: tables, floats, positioning, two-column

I would like to place the following on the same page:

- A double column figure
- A single column figure
- A single column table

I want the placement to look something like this:

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can set a multitude of things inside a floating environment. Below I've created a single `figure*` floating environment for capturing the wide (two-column) figure. However, just below it (inside the same float), I've set a `table` and another `figure` inside `minipage`s, making it seem like they are separate and columnar.

[image]

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage{lipsum,capt-of,graphicx}% http://ctan.org/pkg/{lipsum,capt-of,graphicx}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}% Just for this example
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-7]

\begin{figure*}
  \centering\includegraphics[width=.7\linewidth,height=2in]{example-image-a}\par
  \caption{This is a figure caption}

  \vspace*{\floatsep}

  \begin{minipage}{.5\linewidth}
    \centering\begin{tabular}{ccc}
      \hline
      One & Two & Three \\
      Three & One & Two \\
      Two & Three & One \\
      \hline
    \end{tabular}
    \captionof{table}{This is a table caption}
  \end{minipage}%
  \begin{minipage}{.5\linewidth}
    \centering\includegraphics[width=.6\linewidth]{example-image-b}
    \captionof{figure}{This is a figure caption}
  \end{minipage}
\end{figure*}%

\lipsum[8-14]
\end{document}
```

The placement of the figures will always be on top and on the page following the placement within your document text. [`capt-of`](http://ctan.org/pkg/capt-of) helps out with the placement of float-like captions.

Comment: @Werner, My single column table and single column figure are appearing in the left hand column, rather than one of the right and one on the left.  Why is that?

Comment: For some reason, all of the figures are on the same page, but not formatted how I would like (see my comment above), and there is none of the body text on this page, just white space.  Note: my multicolumn figure at the top is actually a figure consisting of three subfigures.

Comment: I figured it out: the /end{minipage} and /begin{minipage} cannot have a line separating them, they must be on consecutive lines.

Comment: @sphere: [`afterpage`](http://ctan.org/pkg/afterpage) and [`geometry`](http://ctan.org/pkg/geometry) aren't needed. The former was from something else I tried, and the latter was just for this example (since I don't have your images/sizes). You also don't need [`lipsum`](http://ctan.org/pkg/lipsum).

Comment: @sphere: Yes, you need to keep the `minipage`s together. And you actually need the `%` to avoid an overfull `\hbox`. See [What is the use of percent signs (`%`) at the end of lines?](http://goo.gl/awJkj)

Comment: I have same problem, but unfortunately the pictures stand on top of next page and NOT in the same page, any help?

Comment: @H'H: That's typical of floats in `twocolumn` mode; they don't appear on the page you use them. I mention this at the end of my post: "The placement of the figures will always be on the top and on the page *following* the placement within your document text."